# 「やる」Uses and definition

Tags: words, definitions

Ok, I see the word やる used in a lot of different contexts, meaning anything from "to kill" to "have sex with" to "make a vehicle go faster" to "give to someone of lower status". I am constantly dumbfounded but its use and I can't seem to see any correlation between these uses, other than that they may mean "to do". However, this is already covered by「する」so I'm not exactly sure what the definition is. Can someone give me a good general definition of「やる」and the ways it's mostly used?